# Xcode Error trying to subclass UIContextMenuConfiguration

Tags: swift, uicontextmenuconfiguration

I'm getting Xcode compiler error when trying to subclass UIContextMenuConfiguration.

Here's simple code that reproduces the problem:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class DateDifferenceContextMenu: UIContextMenuConfiguration {
    init(indexPath: IndexPath, dateDifference: Int) {
        super.init(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: nil)
    }
}
```

The error reads:

> Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIContextMenuConfiguration'.

My super call matches the designated initializer.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My super call matches the designated initializer.

No, it calls a `convenience` initializer.

Change your code to either simply call `super.init()`, or make your initializer be a `convenience` well. I.e.:

```
class DateDifferenceContextMenu: UIContextMenuConfiguration {
    // use either this
    convenience init(indexPath: IndexPath, dateDifference: Int) {
        self.init(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: nil)
    }

    // or this
    init(indexPath: IndexPath, dateDifference: Int) {
        super.init()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're so right! I looked at the class definition and missed that it only has a convenience init(). The true init() is from NSObject.